# Trigonometry triangles

Tags: trigonometry

I have solved a solution about trigonometry but then reached up to this point where I don't know how to solve it. I'm not going to post  the whole question as all I need to solve is this part and I can do the rest by myself. Hope someone can help me thanks.

$$R = \sqrt{(150+ F \cdot \cos(50))^2 +(F \cdot \sin(50))^2}$$

Trying to solve for F

Comment: ...and the question is...??

Comment: how to solve R=√[(150+Fcos50)^2+ (Fsin(50))^2]=200 sorry

Comment: How to solve...for $\;F\;$ or what?!

Comment: yes of course .. its "F"

Comment: any help please?

Answer (score 2):

If you recall that $(\sin X)^2 + (\cos X)^2 = 1$, after you expand the square of the binomial you will only have one trig function, which is a constant anyway.  You can then square both sides of your equation and solve the resulting quadratic equation for $F$.  At the end, remember to check your answer in the original problem, since squaring both sides may introduce spurious solutions.

$$ \sqrt{(150+F \cdot \cos 50)^2 + (F \cdot \sin 50)^2} = 200$$
$$ \sqrt{150^2 + 300 \cdot F \cdot \cos 50 + (F \cdot \cos 50)^2 + (F \cdot \sin 50)^2} = 200$$
$$ \sqrt{150^2 + 300 \cdot F \cdot \cos 50 + F^2} = 200$$
$$ 150^2 + 300 \cdot F \cdot \cos 50 + F^2 = 200^2$$
$$ F^2 + 300 \cdot F \cdot \cos 50 - 17,500 = 0$$

And now continue to solve, either symbolically or numerically.

Comment: But X=50 degrees.. how can that be applied

Comment: sorry but where did the 300 come from? in the second step

Comment: @user110892: $(150+F\cos(50))^2=150^2+\color{#C00000}{2\cdot150}F\cos(50)+F^2\cos^2(50)$

Comment: About the $300$: Note that $(150+y)^2=150^2+300y+y^2$.

Comment: if i use the quadratic formula, will it be correct if a=1,b=192.83(300 x cos50), c=17,500? thanks

Comment: i tried it and does not work

Comment: Did you use c = **-** 17,500?  I get two solutions, around F = 67 and F = **-** 260, which both work in the original equation.